# How to read digital digits from an image (LCD screen) using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I need to extract digital digits from the digital weighing scale. OCR and Pytesseract libraries are not working for this problem statement. Is there any better libraries or solution?
Below is the input image from which I'm trying to extract the digits.
[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1dzY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this article is what you're looking for: https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/

The article demonstrates the use of `OpenCV` to read LCD-digits off of tiny displays.